# select from union of two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `Cars2016` and `Cars2015`, which have exactly the same columns.

I want to simply concatenate these two tables to create this kind of query :

```
SELECT Mark, COUNT(Models) FROM (Cars2015 UNION Cars2016) GROUP BY Mark
```

This query aims to know for each mark how many models it has, cumulating year 2015 and year 2016.

How can I do that **efficently** ?

Thanks !

Comment: I have tried to make an union of two tables, like I wrote above. But it seems this kind of instruction does not exist.

Comment: You can use the `MERGE` storage engine to create a table name that automatically unions the two tables.

Comment: I think you missed reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) on `UNION`. The `UNION` operator combines results of `SELECT` statements and not tables.

Comment: Thank Stuti, I understand that but I look for alternatives...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way is to count in each table, then union that and sum them.

```
SELECT Mark, SUM(count) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT Mark, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM Cars2015
    GROUP BY Mark
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Mark, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM Cars2016
    GROUP BY Mark
) AS u
GROUP BY Mark
```

If you have an index on `Mark` in the tables, the subqueries should be very efficient. Then it's doing a union of relatively small intermediate tables that contain the aggregates, and then combining them.

Another option is to use the [`MERGE` storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html), which allows you to create a virtual table that contains the union of other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
    -- column names here
) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(Cars2015, Cars2016);

SELECT Mark, COUNT(*)
FROM Cars
GROUP BY Mark;
```

Comment: can you please explain why you group by Mark in the subqueries and then again on the main query? Thanks

Comment: Each subquery is going to return its own total for each `Mark`. To get the full total, you have to add them together with `SUM()`.

Comment: I will also check this MERGE feature

Comment: The MERGE feature is much more efficient than the subqueries ! My tables count about 6000000 rows. The subqueries solution last 5 minutes although the MERGE solution last less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Almost the answer I was searching for but what would be equivalent of `Merge Storage Engine` in sql server @Barmar

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SQL-Server. You could try asking in [dba.se]. @SalimShamim

Answer (score 1):

The [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

> - Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns.
> - The columns must also have similar data types.
> - The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order.

Try this:

```
SELECT models_count FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(Models) models_count, Mark FROM Cars2015 
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(Models) models_count, Mark FROM Cars2016
)
GROUP BY Mark
```

Keep in mind that the UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot simply make an UNION to combine two tables... disappointing...

Comment: Sorry did not get it, why you can't use UNION? The query did not worked? if so please let me know what the error is

Comment: I have to check if this is not too much time consuming (the real query is much more complicated)

Comment: This query won't work, you're not selecting `Mark` in the subquery, so you can't group by it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to union the 2 tables in the from clause with a subquery:

```
select mark, count(*)
from
    (select models, mark from Cars2015
     union all
     select models, mark from Cars2016) t
group by mark
```

If you would like to get the overall count only (you do not have the mark field in the select list), then I would use 2 subueries in the select list and add them up:

```
select (select count(models) from Cars2015) + (select count(models) from Cars2016) as total_models
```

Comment: @barmar thanks, but I saw that and even extended the answer, so had to roll back your edition.

Comment: He doesn't seem to want the overall count, he has `GROUP BY Mark` in his query.

Comment: @Barmar this is why is provided both solutions, not just one of them

Comment: He never asked for the other solution. The question specifically says "for each mark how many models it have".

Comment: It was just a typo that he left `Mark` out of the select list, he's fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar I could not have possibly known this at the time when I wrote the answer.

Comment: @Nahouto no, it is not your fault, it is Barmar's because he cannot let it go. These things happen, and I was happy to provide a solution for both interpretation of the question. Nor harm done, and I'm glad to have an OP who quickly reacts to comments.

Comment: Thank you Shadow !